# Datatables Bootstrap4 - Uncaught (in promise) Cannot extend unknown button type: create

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, datatables

I have a requirement to display a table, with all CRUD operations.

I am using  DataTables for the first time. I have gone through so many post but people have used PHP, and I have no idea about PHP. I am just simply using Datatables with JS.

Please tell me If I am going in any wrong direction.

Anyway, here is the error I am getting.

My code is working fine, I am able to fetch Data. But I want to use inbuilt edit delete feature of Data tables.

Here is my Data table:

```js
$('#table').DataTable(
    {
        data: userArray,
        "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 15, 20, -1], [5, 10, 15, 20, "All"]],
        "pageLength": 10,
               
        select:true,

        buttons: [
            { extend: "create", editor: editor },
            { extend: "edit",   editor: editor },
            { extend: "remove", editor: editor }
        ],

        columns: [
            { title: ' User ID' },
            { title: "firstName" },
            { title: 'Last Name' },
            { title: "Email" },

        ],
});
```

This is the error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Cannot extend unknown button type: create

script-

Comment: "_I want to use inbuilt edit delete feature of Data tables_": DataTables does not have built-in edit and delete features. You can either purchase the [DataTables Editor](https://editor.datatables.net/), or continue using DataTables and write your own CRUD logic.

Comment: For an example, see the official manual page for your [`create` button](https://editor.datatables.net/reference/button/create): _"Please note - this property requires the Editor extension for DataTables."_.